# Encoding for JSON cookie data?

Tags: javascript, json, cookies, encoding

**Do you really need to encode JSON.stringify when saving in cookie?**

I tested it out and IE8+ and chrome works just fine without encoding (encodeURIComponent) the actual data. Problem with encoding is you are limited to 4096 bytes, and a lot of the items in JSON will be encoded causing a larger increase in byte size.

I would be saving variables like this, doesn't seem like encoding is really required. 
(only 345 bytes)

```
{ 
  "s": 
  "p":"1",
  "c":"nameofsomething",
  "i":"56456,54115,878451,651451,65156,878941,5165165,54545,22115,874845",
  "t":"1407515818100",
  "gcid":"CPOa-ZTbpL4CFWdo7AodTnQA3A",
  "k":"54154154"
}
```

When I extract the cookie, everything is preserved. I know it is best practice to do encoding, but saving the bytes and keeping the cookie clean would be better.

*Encoding would look like this* (545 Bytes) about 200 increase because of the encoding

```
 %7B%22s%22%3A%7B%22p%22%3A%221%22%2C%22c%22%3A%22nameofsomething%22%2C%22i%22%3A%2256456%2C54115%2C878451%2C651451%2C65156%2C878941%2C5165165%2C54545%2C22115%2C874845%22%2C%22t%22%3A%221407515818100%22%2C%22gcid%22%3A%22CPOa-ZTbpL4CFWdo7AodTnQA3A%22%2C%22k%22%3A%2254154154%22%7D%2C%22o%22%3A%7B%7D%7D
```

Comment: I don't think it is necessary to encode like it would be for a URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asking about two different things here:

**JSON ENCODING**

If you are trying to store simple data, then no, JSON encoding is not required. You can manually store `key` and `value` pairs in a cookie with no difficulty.  Cookies are very good at this.

If, on the other hand, you have a complex object like your example then JSON encoding is the best way.  If you don't use JSON encoding, you'll need some other way to handle `key/value` encoding, and by the time you end up handling tested objects you'll have just created a poor version of JSON.  So, use JSON and save the headaches.

**encodeURIComponent**

Not needed.  A cookie is not a URI, nor is it a URI component.

**Other**

The JSON encoding will handle any unicode encoding that needs done.

Right off the bat I'm having a hard time imagining any encoding that needs to be done that wouldn't be handled by JSON.

Comment: Thanks. that makes sense. Just wanted to be sure. And when you said JSON encoding, you mean just turning js objects into json.stringify?

Comment: To use more correct wording, `JSON.stringify` takes an object and encodes it into `JSON`, or *JSON encodes* it.  But yes, you understand correctly.

Comment: If your JSON strings contain ; or = you'd need to escape that, which your cookie library code may or may not do for you.